# How to check Length calculated in Cartesian or ellipsoid?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, ellipsoid

I am trying to do offset curve of a line

my layer projection is ESPG:3857 WGS-84\pseudo-Mercator

```
lyr=iface.activeLayer()
geom=lyr.selectedFeatures()[0].geometry()
newgom=geom.offsetCurve(5,2,1,0.0001)
feat=QgsFeature(lyr.fields())
feat.setGeometry(newgom)
lyr.addFeature(feat)
```

it's creating new line but when i calculate distance  its given 4.1(in ellipsoid) and 5(in Cartesian)
i need 5 meters in ellipsoid how can i get?

Comment: Mercator's projection are not optimal for precise measurement, it's well explained in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396041/167243) by @Babel.