Accurate small-scale mile/km markers in QGIS. Qchainage and "Points along geometry" are inaccurate
Looks like Qchainage has been integrated into QGIS as "Points along geometry" and they're basically the same.  But they only work in projected units so they'll be inaccurate for any small-scale map where the scale varies.  Is there an existing way to fix this or should I try forking Qchainage to solve my problem?
Concrete example: I have a vector LineString of the River Loire and I want to show kms upstream from the mouth; it should be about 1012km long.  Working in Mercator (EPSG:3857) I see 1465km because the latitude ranges from 45⁰ to 48⁰.  I could just use a compromise scale and get close, but not exact because the latitude varies.  Tools like "Add geometry attributes" can work in ellipsoidal distances for projected layers so it's surprising that "Points along geometry" can't.

"WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" EPSG:3857 is totally not suitable for accurate measuring of length or area. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396004/getting-accurate-distance-measurements-using-epsg3857-in-qgis.
Why don't you use the official CRS for France which is "RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93" EPSG:2154? In such projection, on the "metropolitan France", the difference between Cartesian distance and ellipsoidal distane is roughly about few hundreds of meters over 1000 km.

Sure, I understand that Mercator is particularly bad for this, but no projection is going to be accurate.  QGIS has the tools to correctly measure projected feature distances so why can't it also have a version of "Points along geometry" that works the same way?
